# QGIS 3.28 - cannot find GDAL commands / MacOS 12.5

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, gdalwarp

I am having trouble linking QGIS to GDAL since a few versions (just updated to 3.28 hopping it would solve the problem but it didn't). For instance, a `Wrap` function returns this error:

```
GDAL command output:
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdalwarp: line 2: dirname: command not found
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdalwarp: line 3: //run_gdal_binary.bash: No such file or directory
Process returned error code 127
```

The funny thing is that `/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdalwarp` exists, and I can call it from the terminal from outside QGIS.

Can anyone see the reason why or has experienced the same problem?

Comment: Are you launching it from OSGEO4 shell?  You can verify the install with OSGEO4 "setup".

Comment: Sorry - launch what? QGIS?

Comment: Are you running GDAL from a command line?  If you are, are you running it inside the OSGeo Shell?   If not, how are you trying to use it?

Comment: No, just running GDAL from the MacOS terminal. Since GDAL doesn't work from within QGIS, I often end up copying the command displayed in the GUI to the terminal. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you put an actual directory name in place of "command" to get it to a dataset?  Does gdalinfo --version return  the correct version?   Example:  gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 your_image_01.tif

Comment: Thanks for your help @CaryH, it seems that the environment variable answer did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - a solution from my co-worker. Under Preferences -> System -> Environment, I unticked the custom variables box entirely. Works now for me!

Comment: Well I wish I could buy your colleague a coffee! Thanks for sharing

Comment: I've already told her I owe her a jar of my haskap jam, haha!

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue and message trying to use the Clip Raster by Mask Layer feature within Q. This is my first time trying to clip a georeferenced image and I'm not super experienced in using command lines, so I'm not certain if I have anything else set wrong. I tried going into settings and updating the Environment to the custom path "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:" but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates.  We are not a discussion list. You have posted a "I'm having this problem too" comment in an Answer block, so this is likely to be removed on review (see the [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) Help Center page).